# add multiple forms to page on button click

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am working on developing a permitting app using django.  This is my first django project so bear with me here...

we have a default utility permit that contains some basic info like property owner and address.  Then from that you can attach a sewer, or water or row or any combination of related tables to the permit.  Basically I am looking for a way to return a page with the default utility permit then have a series of links or buttons to add more forms to that page.

I made some model forms for each of the models and can display them individually on the page

forms.py

```
class UtilityPermitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UtilityPermit
        fields = ['...']


class SewerPermitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SewerPermit
        fields = ['...']


class WaterPermitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WaterPermit
        fields = ['...']
```

I successfully added them to a list and could iterate through and get them to add

views.py

```
class BuildForms(View):
    permits = []
    utility_form = UtilityPermitForm
    sewer_form = SewerPermitForm
    water_form = WaterPermitForm

    permits.append(utility_form)
    permits.append(sewer_form)
    permits.append(water_form)


    template_name = 'engineering/UtilityPermitForm2.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        out_permits = []

        for form in self.permits:
            out_permits.append(form())
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': out_permits})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET.get('testButton'):
            return HttpResponse("I guess")

        form = self.utility_form(request.POST)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def add_permit(self, request, permit):
        # need to get a thing to add a permit to the list
        pass
```

.html

```
{% block content %}
<div>
    <form class="site_form" action={% url 'engineering:utility_permit' %} method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for item in form %}
        {{ item }}
        <hr>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
    <a href="  "></a>
{% endblock content %}
```

so again, my problem is I want to start with a one permit and then have links or buttons to add each form as needed.  I'm a bit at a loss here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
so I have this base permit that comes up when a user navigates to it like so, and I want to have a user click the add sewer permit button or link or whatever

[image]

and then the corresponding permit will come up

[image]

Comment: do u need scrip to add onclick add forms

Comment: any kind of direction.  I didn't know if this needed to be a javascript or Jquery thing of if django could handle it.  Basically i have a few different forms, 1:1 relationships and i would like to have a button, click said button and add a form to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create multiple same form in one page dynamically using formset
see [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

and maybe this [tutorial](https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0) is exactly what you are looking for.

## EDITED

if I understand your question correctly, how about this:

first, it would be better to separate your form with dictionaries instead of list in your **views.py**

```
context = {
  'utility_form': self.utility_form,
  'sewer_form': self.sewer_form,
  'water_form': self.water_form
}
return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

then in your .html file, 
if you want to add one form **each time you click the button**, my trick is:
show your base permit form first (said utility_form), button to add other form, and hide your other form first.

```
<div class="form-container">
   <form class="site_form" action={% url 'engineering:utility_permit' %} method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ utility_form }}
      <div id="additional-forms"></div> <!-- notice this div -->
      <hr>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</div>

<button class="add-sewer-form">Sewer Permit</button>

<div id="sewer-form-template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="sewer-form-container">
        {{ sewer_form }}
    </div>
</div>
```

and then using jquery to add onclick listener, clone that hidden form, then insert it after base form (actually inside div with id `additional-forms`).

```
$('.add-sewer-form').click(function(){
   let sewer_form = $('#sewer-form-template .sewer-form-container:first').clone(true);
   $(sewer_form).appendTo($('#additional-forms'))
});
```

I haven't test it yet, but when you click the add button, it should be give result like this:

```
<div class="form-container">
   <form class="site_form" action={% url 'engineering:utility_permit' %} method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ utility_form }}
      <div id="additional-forms">
         <div class="sewer-form-container">
            {{ sewer_form }}
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</div>

<button class="add-sewer-form">Sewer Permit</button>

<div id="sewer-form-template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="sewer-form-container">
        {{ sewer_form }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it can answer your question :)

Comment: I have looked a bit at formsets, but I don't know if they are exactly what I need.  Form sets appear to work extremely well when you have a 1:many relationship and have a fixed set, like author to book.  My problem is these are a 1:1 but the forms are all different and change depending on the nature of the project.  For example, you may have 1 overall permit that contains a utility and ROW permit. and the next overall permit that is a utility sewer and water.  so i need to add different forms to a single view not multiple instances of a single form.  thanks

Comment: is it means you want to clone the <form> tag instead each time user click the button?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just need a method or procedure to add different additional forms to this base form as needed.

Comment: I have edited my answer, hope it can solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

1. First add the button

   ```
   <button><button>
   ```
2. Then add onclick attribute to it which will help react on click

   ```
   <button onclick='do'><button>
   ```
3. Then create script that contain the function to display the other form

   ```
   <script>
   function do() {
           document.getElementById('form').innerHTML ='add your form here'
   }
   </script>
   ```

## all together

```
    <button onclick='do'><button>
    <script>
    function do() {
            document.getElementById('form').innerHTML ='add your form here'
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: see the post again

Comment: Thank you! Now this answer can help more people, and also result in more upvotes.

Comment: oo i thought u asked(as que without ans don't get highlight that'y )